# foreach linq2sql string problem

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi all when I am trying to match a letter O in my database I get string format errors. I have tried a few things now and googles alot but still cant resolve this error

```
const string st1 = ("O");
var docketcheck = from q in db.Dockets
                  where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text && q.Status.Equals(st1)
                  select q;

foreach (Docket d in docketcheck)
{
  if (d.EngName.Equals("NULL"))
  {
    isEngNameNull = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (isEngNameNull)
{
  txtDisplay.Clear();
  txtDisplay.ReadOnly = false;
  var engs = new EngStart();
  engs.ShowDialog(this);
}
else
{
  var sub = new machinesel();
  txtDisplay.Clear();
  sub.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

What is the correct way to check if my mssql database contains the letter O in the above code

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `Status` is a string column?

Comment: No not at all I did just have where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text && q.Status.Equals("O")

Comment: Try replacing it with a 0 (zero), without quotes: `q.Status.Equals(0)`

Comment: Well its not a zero it O for open, the column in the DB is a nchar(10),null, sorry all new to this sql and linq2sql thanks

Comment: what do you mean by string format errors?

Comment: Please include the exception or build error that you are receiving so that the problem can be identified.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is fine provided that q.Status is a string type column.
Here is the lambda way to do it if you are interested.

```
db.Dockets.Where(q => q.DocketNum == txtDisplay && q.Status == "O")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and when I tested an equivalent query on my machine it worked without issue.

You could tidy your code up a bit so that it only pulls back the count of matching records like this:

```
const string st1 = "O";

var docketcheck =
    from q in db.Dockets
    where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text
    where q.Status == st1
    where d.EngName == "NULL"
    select q;

if (docketcheck.Any())
{
    txtDisplay.Clear();
    txtDisplay.ReadOnly = false;
    var engs = new EngStart();
    engs.ShowDialog(this);
}
else
{
    var sub = new machinesel();
    txtDisplay.Clear();
    sub.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

I hope this helps.